# How do I authenticate with Github when using Gradle source code dependencies?

Tags: github, gradle, dependency-management

I'm trying to declare a source dependency in a gradle build. In settings.gradle, I have defined:

```
sourceControl {
    gitRepository("https://github.com/my-organization/myRepo.git") {
        producesModule("com.jrandrews:my-dependency")
    }
}
```

In build.gradle, I have declared:

```
configurations{ application }

dependencies {
    application('com.jrandrews:my-dependency') { 
        version { branch = 'master' }
    }
}
```

I've tried several variations on the theme to try to declare an auth method and auth properties. "gradle dependencies --stacktrace" always results in a failure of the form:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':dependencies'.
    ...
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not locate branch 'master' for Git repository at https://github.com/....
    ...
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/***.git: Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:161)
    at org.gradle.vcs.git.internal.GitVersionControlSystem.getRemoteRefs(GitVersionControlSystem.java:103)
    ... 136 more
```

There are open bugs on this, apparently, but people seem to be successfully using this dependency system, and I can't believe they're all doing it without authentication. Does anyone know how to declare authentication that this dependency declaration can use?

Comment: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8245; I'm guessing that I'm going to have to write the auth code.

Comment: have you had any success on authenticating either using https or ssh?

Comment: Please, any update?

Comment: I was never able to get this working, no. :I ended up checking out the module, building it locally, and including the .jar file.

Comment: Hi, are any updates about this? facing the same problem that i need a way to set authentication infos. ssh or password would be possible.

Comment: No; I haven't worked in it since my last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it will not work for now.

- The HTTPS won't work because there's no implementation for HTTPS Auth: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/version-control/src/main/java/org/gradle/vcs/git/internal/GitVersionControlSystem.java
- The SSH won't work cause its default auth needs to be updated to work with new key standards https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/20387/files